# Error to show it fullname

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

When I write both first and last name in as I'd like it will be presented any new text when they are no longer empty both.

Right now I get this one wrong.

```
 {{fullname}}
```

**Create.cshtml**

my button is beyond my controller which caters to my angula

```
<div ng-app="UserCreatenNow" ng-controller="CreateUserNow">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Fornavn)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Fornavn, new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
               @ng_model = "firstname",
                @placeholder = HelperTextClass.HelperText.placeholderInfo.Fornavn
           })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Fornavn, "", new
           {
               @class = "label label-danger"
           })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Efternavn)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Efternavn, new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
               @ng_model = "lastname",
               @placeholder = HelperTextClass.HelperText.placeholderInfo.Efternavn
           })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Efternavn, "", new
           {
               @class = "label label-danger"
           })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**User.js**

This one file I download in the bottom of the page. and I'll pick angularJs CDN at the top to secure me that I get it.

```
var app = angular.module('UserCreatenNow', []);

app.controller('CreateUserNow', function ($scope) {
    //checking on first name and surname are written.
    if ($scope.firstname != null && $scope.lastname != null) {
        //prints it together
        $scope.fullname = "Welcome to " + $scope.firstname + " " + $scope.lastname;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.fullname = "Sign up now";
    }
});
```

You can see it [image here](http://postimg.org/image/knk2thc3f/)

**UPDATE:**

```
<head>
<title>Hello world</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/Scripts/app")
</head>
```

create.cshtml

```
<form>
<div ng-app="UserCreatenNow" ng-controller="CreateUserNow">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Fornavn)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Fornavn, new
                   {
                       @ng_model = "firstname",
                       @class = "form-control",
                       @placeholder = HelperTextClass.HelperText.placeholderInfo.Fornavn
                   })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Fornavn, "", new
                   {
                       @class = "label label-danger"
                   })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Efternavn)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Efternavn, new
                   {
                       @ng_model = "lastname",
                       @class = "form-control",
                       @placeholder = HelperTextClass.HelperText.placeholderInfo.Efternavn
                   })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Efternavn, "", new
                   {
                       @class = "label label-danger"
                   })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Kon)
                        @Html.DropDownList("SelectedKon", (SelectList)ViewBag.KonList, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control",
                   })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.KategoriNyhedsbrev)
                        @Html.DropDownList("SelectedKategoriNyhedsbrev", (SelectList)ViewBag.KategoriBrevList, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control",
                   })
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Birthday)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Birthday, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control",
                       type = "date"
                   })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Birthday, "", new
                   {
                       @class = "label label-danger"
                   })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-actions">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label class="rememberme">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.OpretCheckbox)
                        </label>
                        @Html.ActionLink(HelperTextClass.HelperText.OpretBrugerCheck, "brugerbetingelser", "information")
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p class="label label-danger"></p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{fullname}}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

js file here:

```
var app = angular.module('UserCreatenNow', []);

app.controller('CreateUserNow', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watchGroup(['firstname', 'lastname'], function (firstname, lastname, $scope) {
        if ($scope.firstname != null && $scope.lastname != null) {
            //prints it together
            $scope.fullname = "Welcome to " + $scope.firstname + " " + $scope.lastname;
        } else {
            $scope.fullname = "Sign up now";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure you included angular js library in your page ?

Comment: thinking on the CDN or the file?

Comment: Angular is not initiated. You should see errors in the console. Check them and try to figure out what is wrong there.

Comment: @RomanHutnyk it error are here: http://postimg.org/image/9cnhg2651/

Comment: I've tried to look at it for quite some time and I can not see the error / problem here

Comment: Remove the d in your else  part !

Comment: @Venkatraman i have its now. :)

Comment: @J.Petersen have you included user.js file? Error says there is no CreateUserNow function.

Comment: @RomanHutnyk I am sure that I have it, the loader also into the page when it is.

Comment: refer this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: @J.Petersen, check my answer

Comment: @Venkatraman Thanks for help, its help me :)

Comment: Accept the answer or let me know if any other is still exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope.watchGroup`. check the below working demo with snippet. I used `Angular 1.4`

```js
var app = angular.module('UserCreatenNow', []);

app.controller('CreateUserNow', function ($scope) {

    $scope.$watchGroup(['firstname', 'lastname'], function(firstname, lastname, $scope) {
    if ($scope.firstname != null && $scope.lastname != null) {
        //prints it together
        $scope.fullname = "Welcome to " + $scope.firstname + " " + $scope.lastname;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.fullname = "Sign up now";
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="UserCreatenNow" ng-controller="CreateUserNow">

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" ng-model="lastname">
            </div>
        </div>

        {{fullname}}
   </div>
```

Comment: It tells me still the same mistake as I posted earlier.

Comment: what is your current issue

Comment: make sure you use angular 1.4 or above and check the html in the answer.

Comment: it works is still not .. I really do not know what is going wrong. I have done exactly what you have told me to do.

i have 1.4.8 from CDN

Comment: updated the answer. see the working demo with 1.4.8. Make sure your out html looks similar to my answer

Comment: Could it perhaps be because the drive Localhost it does not work? and i have update my code.

Comment: No. some problem in your  html code. please share the rendered html output from browser rather updating ASP.net code

Comment: It does not in any way. I just stop here and try something different framework javascript when I have spent soon as 12-13 hours on this. Sorry but i will giv u +1 for its.